# Arabic translation of content on sharepoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, language-pack, machine-translation

We have Sharepoint Communication Site in Sharepoint Server 2019 hosted on our premises. We have enabled the language feature and the site interface is now displayed in Arabic. However, we want to know the options of providing the Arabic version of content for the same page. For example, on the English site, English content is displayed and on the Arabic site, Arabic content is displayed. Any options to achieve it please?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Modern Communication Site in SharePoint 2019, then as per my knowledge this is not possible,

If you are using classic publishing site, then you can use [Variations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/variations-overview) feature but **it's deprecated** by Microsoft so you will not get any support from Microsoft.